# Unexpected Error Pages in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I'm aware of the ways to set up custom error pages for *expected* errors.  However, what I'd like to do is a set up a pretty, catch-all page that viewers will see on *any* error.  So for example instead of "Unable to connect..." or whatnot, they get "We're sorry, an error occurred...".

Is there a view that can be modified or overridden to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The error views are defined in `/application/views/errors/html`. There is one for php errors and one for exceptions. If you don't want to edit those you can extend the `CI_Exceptions` class and override show_php_error or what ever else you would like. If you wanted to try that you should create a file called "MY_Exceptions.php" in the `/application/core/` folder and in it put....

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    public function show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
    {
        echo "Caught random php Error...";
    }
}
```